# How to provide HttpContextBase for the RequestAuthentication function in Oauth?

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I am developing a website by using ASP.NET web forms. I want to implemnt open auth login for famous identity providers. So to do that I downloaded Dotnetopenauth extension for ASP.NET from NUGet packages. Everythings fine.

Now I have a code a like this.

```
        Uri ui=new Uri("~/Login.aspx");


        DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient("***", "***********");
        fb.RequestAuthentication(context, ui);
```

To first parameter of the RequestAuthentication it is asking for HttpContextBase. But how to give it? I tried to use HttpContext.Current. but its give me a error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the wrapper

```
 fb.RequestAuthentication( new HttpContextWrapper( HttpContext.Current ), ui);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked. Can you explain what is the use of HttpContextWrapper?

Comment: It works as an adapter between two classes of different interfaces. Its primary use is to adapt the context to be the context base.